# Using a scalar variable inside a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, dbeaver, sql-server-2019

I am reviewing someone else's code but I've hit a wall. When I try to execute the provided script I get the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@userId".

I tried to remove the semicolon on line 2 just to try things but that give me the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I'm very confused by this because this exact piece of code works on machines of others, but not on mine. I know there are other ways to write this query but I need to get this to work. **Is there any way to make the variable work as intended in this script without rewriting the whole thing?**

I'm using **Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8) (KB4577194) - 15.0.4073.23 (X64)** on **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**.

```
DECLARE @userId int
SET @userId =:user_id;
                        
WITH bidsplacedtotal AS (
    SELECT amount, user_id, auction_id
    FROM bids WHERE user_id = @userId
)
,bidsreceivedtotal AS (
    SELECT amount, user_id, auction_id
    FROM bids WHERE auction_id IN
    (SELECT id FROM auctions WHERE user_id = @userId)
)
          
SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM bidsplacedtotal) AS placed_total

UNION

SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM bidsreceivedtotal) AS received_total
```

Comment: And what is `:user_id`?

Comment: @GMB A number, `2091` for example

Comment: What happens when you replace `:user_id` in that code with a literal number (`2091`): does the code run?

Comment: It throws exactly the same errors

Comment: Not able to reproduce this behavior: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e611e0ef17857deda6ecb01346a25e6e

Comment: Like I said; it's not my code. But I appreciate the lesson, I'm always eager to learn.

Comment: What tool are you using to send the queries? Does that use semicolon as a batch delimiter?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm getting the same problem with DBeaver, and PHP using the ODBC driver. I'm actually not sure if they use the semicolon as a batch delimiter, and I have no idea how to check honestly.

Comment: Looks like that might be the issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/batches-of-sql-statements?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1482

Comment: @MartinSmith You're right, thanks. I changed the delimiter in DBeaver to something else and the script worked. I'll try to change this for the ODBC driver as well.

Comment: @StefanTeunissen  It would be good to tag the problematic tool and mention it specifically for others searching in the future. Context is important!

Comment: I've got the same issue in DBVisualizer, but it was working correctly in SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to see if it works:

```
DECLARE @userId int
   SELECT @userId = 2091
                        
;WITH bidsplacedtotal AS (
    SELECT amount, user_id, auction_id
    FROM bids WHERE user_id = @userId
)
,bidsreceivedtotal AS (
    SELECT amount, user_id, auction_id
    FROM bids WHERE auction_id IN
    (SELECT id FROM auctions WHERE user_id = @userId)
)
          
SELECT COUNT(amount) as CountAmount FROM bidsplacedtotal) AS placed_total

UNION

SELECT COUNT(amount) as CountAmount FROM bidsreceivedtotal) AS received_total
```